# cv2.imwrite cannot save the srgan output image, it just gives a blank image

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning

SRGAN WORK

Problem is that it wont correctly saves the output image.

```py
#Test - perform super resolution using saved generator model
# Model training link
# https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V9rNj4RxzSruL0nG4JmhwTwHgmc5BYl3/view?usp=sharing

from keras.models import load_model

import cv2

from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img,img_to_array,array_to_img

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

#Model link

# https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CgJ9KUYAdIx9yFaUnKz-2Y_Jrrbyhxmq/view?usp=sharing

generator = load_model('D:/srgan/data/testsrgan/model/gen_e_11.h5', compile=False)

# Low resolution image of dimension 128x128

lr_test =load_img("im3.jpg")

lr_arr=img_to_array(lr_test)/255

lr_arr=np.expand_dims(lr_arr,axis=0)

#High resolution image of dimension 512x512

hr_test =load_img("im3.jpg")

hr_arr=img_to_array(hr_test)/255

hr_arr=np.expand_dims(hr_arr,axis=0)


src_image, tar_image = lr_arr,hr_arr

# generate image from source

gen_image = generator.predict(src_image)


# plot all three images

plt.figure(figsize=(16, 8))

plt.subplot(231)

plt.title('LR Image')

plt.imshow(src_image[0,:,:,:])

plt.subplot(232)

plt.title('Superresolution')

plt.imshow(gen_image[0,:,:,:])

plt.subplot(233)

plt.title('Orig. HR image')

plt.imshow(tar_image[0,:,:,:])

plt.show()

cv2.imwrite("test.jpg",np.reshape(gen_image, (512,512, 3)))# It saves blank image of dimension 512x512. Just a black image.

cv2.imwrite("test1.jpg",gen_image) # It saves an empty file of size 0 bytes.
```

With all these methods used, only matplotlib works but I want full resultant image to be saved and opened later.

Comment: This is an srgan based project. I can't save the full resultant image using opencv. The high resolution image is 512 x512 and low resolution 128x128. I am expecting an output image of 512x512. The result can be viewed only by matplotlib. When tried to save by opencv it just saves as black image or image file of size 0 bytes if itsn't reshaped to 512x512.

Comment: before saving using `cv2`, normalize the image to range 0-255 and save it using `uint8` data type

Comment: I know this isn't a solution to your case but did you try saving the image with plt.imsave() ?

Comment: It doesnt works. I can save the image using matplotlib, but it will be small.